# How to assign unique ID to element for each component instance

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I've got a ReactJS component that I have multiple instances of. 
I want to change components elements' css with an on-click.

I tried to reference the specific component element by ID, but the problem is that currently, the ID or each component instance is the same, which results in all components changing.

I'm thinking of passing a unique reference to each component, but I don't know how to change it in the element's html id's . In Angular a solution is like this:

```
<span id="{{ 'object-' + $component_idx }}"></span>
```

is there something similar to achieve this in React? Or is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

**Here's what I'm doing right now:**

*calling component instance in parent:*

```
<Entry
    title={instance_title}
    number={i}
  />
```

*Creating an Entry component:*

```
class Entry extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { preference: 4 };
  }


preferencer(idx) {
    // change emoji size
    let oldPref = this.state.preference;
    if (idx == this.state.preference) {
      this.state.preference = 4;
      document.getElementById("emo" + idx).style.transform = "scale(1)";
    } else if (idx != this.state.preference) {
      this.state.preference = idx;
      document.getElementById("emo" + idx).style.transform = "scale(2)";
      if (oldPref != 4) {
        document.getElementById("emo" + oldPref).style.transform = "scale(1)";
      }
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <EmojiWrap id="emo0" onClick={() => this.preferencer(0)}>
           {" "}
         </EmojiWrap>
         <EmojiWrap id="emo1" onClick={() => this.preferencer(1)}>
           
         </EmojiWrap>
         <EmojiWrap id="emo2" onClick={() => this.preferencer(2)}>
           
        </EmojiWrap>
      </Wrapper>
     );
    }
 }
export default Entry;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add more code? How are you rendering the multiple components?

Comment: I think it depends on how you want to change the style. I don't see why you would use an unique identifier for each component.
As @MukeshSoni suggested, could you add more code?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I've added my code!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using the ID's for styling, you can use a checker on the styles property and onClick can change the state directly, as such:

```
<EmojiWrap style={this.state.preference === 1 ? {transform: "scale(2)"} : {}} 
onClick={() => this.setState({preference: 1})} >
...
</emojiWrap>

//repeat this for every emoji, changing the number  and emoji inside only
```

thus by eliminating the need for the preferencer function.

Comment: Interesting, but It yields the error:

The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

Comment: Sorry about that, you can replace with style={this.state.preference === 1 ? {transform: "scale(2)"} : { }}